# how to Store the radio button value in another page

Tags: php, html, radio-button

i am try to Store the radio button value in another page
   and i am using 2 pages one is win.php here in this page fetch oracle data and select data by radio
   buttom click on submit then selected value goes to second page in input text fields

```
win.php

<form action="win.php" method="post">
   <table width="500" border="0" align="center">  
   <tr>  
     <th width="98"> <div align="center">Select:</div></th> 
     <th width="98"> <div align="center">Operator ID:</div></th>  
     <th width="98"> <div align="center">Operator Name:</div></th>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
   </tr>
<?  
    while($objResult = oci_fetch_array($objParse, OCI_RETURN_NULLS+OCI_ASSOC)) { 
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            echo $OPRID = $_POST["OPRID"];
        }
?>  
   <tr>  
      <td>
          <div align="center">
              <input type="radio" name="OPRID" id="radio" value=<?=$objResult["OPRID"];?>/>
          </div>
      </td>  
      <td><div align="center"><?=$objResult["OPRID"];?></td>
      <td><div align="center"><?=$objResult["OPRDEFNDESC"];?></td>
   </tr>
<?  
    }  
?>  
   </table>  
<?  
   oci_free_statement($objParse);
   oci_close($ora_conn); 
 }
 ?>
```

and other is input.php

```
<input id="OPRID" name="OPRID" type="text" size="40"/>
```

and problem is how to store radio button value in this input.php text fields......

Comment: Use input type hidden

Comment: It's not about oracle.

Comment: why not about oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POST your form to input.php

```
// win.php
<form action="input.php" method="POST">
```

and then load the posted data from the radio button with `$_POST['OPRID']`

```
// input.php
$radiovalue = isset($_POST['OPRID']) ? $_POST['OPRID'] : "";
<input id="OPRID" name="OPRID" type="text" size="40" value="<?php echo $radiovalue; ?>"/>
```

Comment: but problem is when i am open this input.php page i have getting error
<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: OPRID in <b>

Comment: Then change `<?php echo $_POST['OPRID']; ?>` to `<?php echo (isset($_POST['OPRID']) ? $_POST['OPRID'] : ""); ?> `